# Не работает запрос с multipart загруженный в ammo

Tags: яндекс-танк

Запрос работает в curl и requests Питона, но при загрузке в ammo.txt не распознается сервером.
Пример curl:
curl --noproxy  -X POST -F "profileId=7" -F "phone=89169999999" -F "audio=@Cartoon-02.wav" http:///api/v1/verify

Пользуюсь генератором ammo
Он создает подобное

```
77431
POST /api/v1/verify HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: python-requests/2.22.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 28863
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=54bf3f0d88f2e6a8f69a130d81d13179

b'--54bf3f0d88f2e6a8f69a130d81d13179\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="profileId"\r\n\r\n7\r\n--54bf3f0d88f2e6a8f69a130d81d13179\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="phone"\r\n\r\n89169999999\r\n--54bf3f0d88f2e6a8f69a130d81d13179\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="audio"; filename="Cartoon-02.wav"\r\n\r\nRIFFdo\x00\x00WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x11+\x0... бинарный код ...\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\r\n--54bf3f0d88f2e6a8f69a130d81d13179--\r\n'
```

Запрос не принимается

```
{
  "message": "{'profileId': ['Missing data for required field.']}"
}
```

Если создавать без вложения, то формируется urlencoded, и он принимается сервером, но отсутствует вложение. При создании multipart - не передается не только файл, но и данные формы.

Дело не в питоновской добавке "b''", ее убираешь - результат тот же.
Честно говоря, отчаялся, не понимаю, можно ли приспособить танк под запросы с формой.

Дело в кодировке? В документации нет нормального примера с бинарником, переданным таким образом.

load.yaml

```
phantom:
  address: [server]
  ammofile: ammo.txt
  load_profile:
    load_type: rps # schedule load by defining requests per second
    schedule: const(1,10)
  writelog: all
  ammo_type: phantom

console:
  enabled: true # enable console output
telegraf:
  enabled: false # let's disable telegraf monitoring for the first time
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрались. Дело в том, что под 3-м Питоном генератор аммо от Яндекса создаёт какую-то чушь, с лишними тегами ('b') и не в той кодировке.
При этом если созданный файл редактировать во внешних приложениях типа Notepad++, то есть ощущение, что что-то теряется, он перестаёт нормально работать.

Решение было в том, что мы запустили ammo_generator под *вторым* Питоном, взлетело:

```
phantom:
  address: [server]
  ammofile: ammo.txt
  load_profile:
    load_type: rps # schedule load by defining requests per second
    schedule: const(1,10) # stepped load from 5 to 15 rps, with 5 rps steps, step duration 10s.
  writelog: all
  ammo_type: phantom

console:
  enabled: true # enable console output
telegraf:
  enabled: false # let's disable telegraf monitoring for the first time
```

Аммо:

```
29053
POST /api/v1/verify HTTP/1.1
Host: [server]
Content-Length: 28900
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=7ca535f423264c763e6eef705eac88af

--7ca535f423264c763e6eef705eac88af
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="phone"

89169999999
--7ca535f423264c763e6eef705eac88af
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profileId"

7
--7ca535f423264c763e6eef705eac88af
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="audio"; filename="Cartoon-02.wav"
Content-Type: audio/wav
Expires: 0

RIFFdo  WAVEfmt      +  +    data@o  ЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂ
UqS”­‡‚ЎЈvYsUFЉ‡m›©“Љ‹~ <...> ЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂЂ
--7ca535f423264c763e6eef705eac88af--
```

Тут именно фишка в том, что сразу из питоновского кода генерить аммо и не трогать и не редактировать - есть ощущение, что копипаст может порушить структуру, а пушка к ней очень чувствительна - и ammo_generator.py на сайте яндекса запускать только под *вторым* Питоном, а не третьим.

Принт в файл вывода можно делать так: python make_ammo.py > ammo.txt

Answer (score 0):

Заголовок "Host" - это **обязательный** заголовок для HTTP/1.1, подробнее читайте https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616

curl добавляет его за вас, в случае с фантомом нужно явно указывать все заголовки, иначе веб-сервер может вести себя непредсказуемо.

Попробуйте сформировать запрос в корректном формате и напишите помогло ли это.